# jQuery UI dialog and YouTube

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, youtube

I am trying to use jQuery dialog with YouTube video.

The code for jQuery is:

```
var template = $(document.createElement('div')).attr('class', 'sample').attr('id', 'sample').text('Hello World');
    $('body').append(template);
    $(template).dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        height: 280,
        width: 600,
        modal: true,
        resizable: false,
        open: function (){},
        close: function () {},
        buttons: {}          
    });
```

The code for YouTube is:

```
<iframe title="Video" width="640" height="390" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/gVjqL-9Fh3E" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

The video is already on the page. There is also a button on the page. Upon clicking the button the above dialog opens. So, the problem is when the dialog opens, the dialog is behind the video. Tried googling, there is a solution for similar problem when the video is embedded using Object and embed but nothing when iframe is used. Any directions people as to what can be done to deal with this issue?

Comment: I'm confused. Is the YouTube video in the dialog, or on the main page (and you're trying to show the dialog _above_ the video?)

Comment: So, the video is already on the page. There is also a button on the page. Upon clicking the button the dialog opens. The dialog is behind the video.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does adding `<param name="wmode" value="transparent">` to the `object` being used to embed the flash content help?

I haven't done any flash development in a long time, but I seem to remember running into a similar problem once, and this fixed it. Currently YouTube embeds via an `iframe` by default, but I think you can still use the old embed method with the `object` tag.

Edit: For the iframe url try adding: &wmode=transparent

Comment: Yeah, but the requirement is to use iframe as it is for a CMS and this method allows the user to provide only one tag.

Comment: Add &amp;wmode=transparent to the url and try that.

Comment: Nice, works perfect! now need to check what I would need to do to support other video sites. Thx!